# R - I have a for loop to identify outliers in each row for one column - how to loop to look across every column?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a long (row per pt) dataset, with columns for numerous variables. I've created a for loop to run over each row and print the id of every participant that is an outlier based on their results for a specific column/variable. In the below example looking at column x, this correctly identifies Pt6 as an outlier on variable x.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c("Pt1","Pt2", "Pt3","Pt4", "Pt5", "Pt6"), 
                  x=c(1,3,3,3,5,31),
                  y=c(2,9,10,10.5,10.5,11),
                  z=c(34,34,34,35,68,36))

for (row in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  variable <- dat[row, "x"]
  id <- dat[row, "id"]
  
  if((variable>(mean(dat$x, na.rm=TRUE) 
                + (2*sd(dat$x, na.rm=TRUE))))
     |
     (variable<(mean(dat$x, na.rm=TRUE) 
                - (2*sd(dat$x, na.rm=TRUE))))
  )
  {
    print(id)
  }}
```

However, I'd like to identify all participants that are an outlier based on each column individually - in the example data, it should identify Pt6 because of their x value AND Pt1 because of their y value AND Pt5 because of their z value.

I know I'll need to nest another for loop to go over the columns, something like the below, but it only identifies Pt5 so I think it is not looking at the columns individually?

```
for (row in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  
  for (col in 1:ncol(dat)) 
    
  value <- dat[row, col]
  id <- dat[row, "id"]
  
  if((value>(mean(dat[[col]], na.rm=TRUE) 
                + (2*sd(dat[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))))
     |
     (value<(mean(dat[[col]], na.rm=TRUE) 
                - (2*sd(dat[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))))
  )
  {
    print(id)
  }}
```

I'm new to forloops (obviously) - trying to get out of the bad habit of copy pasting. I've tried looking at other answers but I can't see how to apply it here / they're not in R. Any help appreciated! Open to different approaches altogether (e.g apply based ones) but would quite like to plug my gap in forloop understanding if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by looking at your `for-loops`. You can optimize these quite easily, by storing your results (mean and such) in a variable, so these do not have to be recomputed. This is by far the slowest part of your loop so the boost will be significant. In your first code example this would look like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c("Pt1","Pt2", "Pt3","Pt4", "Pt5", "Pt6"), 
                  x=c(1,3,3,3,5,31),
                  y=c(2,9,10,10.5,10.5,11),
                  z=c(34,34,34,35,68,36))
# Pre-define variables
mu <- mean(dat$x, na.rm = TRUE)
sd2 <- 2 * sd(dat$x, na.rm = TRUE)
upper <- mu + sd2
lower <- mu - sd2
# Create storage
rows <- logical(n <- nrow(dat))
for (row in 1:n) {
  variable <- dat[row, "x"]  
  if(variable > upper || variable < lower)
  {
    # Set index to true, for row being an "outlier"
    rows[row] <- TRUE 
  }
}
# Print outlier rows
dat[rows,]
```

For you next loop, it would make sense to either store a matrix of "outlier indicators" or just the row/column pair, for example as a list. You are getting most of the way already. It makes sense to loop over columns in the outer loop, so you once again avoid recomputing mean and standard deviation at every iteration

```
# Specify columns to iterate over
cols <- names(dat)[-1]
# Storage for outliers
outliers <- list()
for(j in cols){
  # Pre-define variables
  mu <- mean(dat[, j], na.rm = TRUE)
  sd2 <- 2 * sd(dat[, j], na.rm = TRUE)
  upper <- mu + sd2
  lower <- mu - sd2
  # Create storage
  rows <- logical(n <- nrow(dat))
  for (row in 1:n) {
    variable <- dat[row, j]

    if(variable > upper || variable < lower)
    {
      # Set index to true, for row being an "outlier"
      rows[row] <- TRUE 
    }
  }
  outliers[[j]] <- rows
}
# Print outliers 
dat[outliers[['x']], ]
dat[outliers[['y']], ]
dat[outliers[['z']], ]
```

Now this is one method for doing it. But many functions in `R` are vectorized. So we could simplify this massively. Vectorization basically allows us to evaluate functions over vector inputs and this is also possible for logical comparison such as `<` `<=` `==` and so on. This allows us to remove the row iteration in this case, and simplifies the code drastically. For example the first code would be reduced to

```
# Only 1 column
mu <- mean(dat$x)
sd2 <- sd(dat$x) * 2
upper <- mu + sd2 
lower <- mu - sd2
rows <- dat$x > upper | datx < lower
# Alternative, cheeky 1 liner:
rows <- abs(dat$x) - (mean(dat$x) + 2 * sd(dat$x)) > 0
```

while the latter could even be done as

```
outliers <- lapply(dat[, c('x', 'y', 'z')], 
                   function(x)x[abs(x) - (mean(x) + 2 * sd(x)) > 0])
dat[outliers[['x']], ]
dat[outliers[['y']], ]
dat[outliers[['z']], ]
```

where I replace the `for-loop` with a call to `lapply` which will iterate over the columns in `dat` and apply the `function` specified, returning a list for each column. There is no real performance gain from replacing the `for-loop`, but it is easier to read for smaller calls like this.

Answer (score 0):

The following code computes the column means and SD's first. Then the limits of mu +/- 2sd. Then uses a `sapply` loop to see which column elements are within those limits. Finally, it subsets the `id` column based on the results of `sapply`.

```
means <- colMeans(dat[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
sds <- apply(dat[-1], 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
ci95 <- means + cbind(-2*sds, 2*sds)

out <- sapply(seq_along(dat[-1]), function(i){
  v <- dat[-1][[i]]
  v < ci95[i, 1] | v > ci95[i, 2]
})
out
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

dat[[1]][rowSums(out) > 0]
#[1] "Pt1" "Pt5" "Pt6"
```